# Django query aggregation into list of dicts

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, aggregation

I'm using Django and Postgres and I have the current setup (mockup):

Class A:
name=models.CharField()
b=models.ManyToManyField(to=B)

Class B:
c=ForeignKey(to=C)
amount=models.IntegerField()

I need to create a query that, starting from A returns all the values in B as a list of dictionaries.
I tried JSONBAgg and ArrayAgg but had no luck while trying to save multiple fields.

Example query:
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.general import JSONBAgg
A.objects.annotate(test=JSONBAgg('amount')).values('name', 'test') WORKS!
A.objects.annotate(test=JSONBAgg('amount', 'c__id')).values('name', 'test') DOES NOT WORK!

How do I get a list of dicts with multiple values instead of a list of strings?

Comment: Can you paste your models and views here, it would give more clarity to answer

Comment: Please show your actual model definitions and what you have tried with the output.

Answer (score -3):

May be this code will work when I applied so it worked.

```
res = defaultdict(list)
for sub in test_list:
    for key in sub:
        res[key].append(sub[key])
      
print("The extracted dictionary : " + str(dict(res)))
```